# Conexão com o banco de dados muito lenta

Tags: mysql

Eu não sei o que aconteceu que agora a conexão com o banco de dados está demorando muito. Antes era rápido dava a resposta se estava conectado ou não...
agora leva uns 15 minutos e meu pc não funciona direito fica tudo travando principalmente o eclipse...

Agora qualquer projeto dá esse "bug"... onde será que estou errando?

O conector que estou usando é esse, já tentei o atual também deu na mesma...
mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin-jar

```
package br.com.Sistema.dal;

import java.sql.*;
public class ModuloConexao {
    //metodo por estabelecer conexao com o banco
    public static Connection conector() {
        java.sql.Connection conexao = null;

        // linha abaixo "chama" o driver
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        // armazenando informaçoes referente ao bd
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teste";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "vertrigo";

        // Estabecendo conexao ao Banco de Dados
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            System.out.println(conexao);
            return conexao;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // a linha abaixo serve de apoio para esclarecer o erro
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Não há Conexao com o Banco de Dados");
            return null;

        }


    }
}
```

Tela de Login

```
package TelaPrincipal.telas;




import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;


import java.sql.*;
import br.com.Sistema.dal.ModuloConexao;


public class TelaLogin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conexao = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TelaLogin frame = new TelaLogin();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TelaLogin() {
        conexao = ModuloConexao.conector();
        System.out.println(conexao);

        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("          < Sistema de Usuario >");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 330, 191);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);


        JLabel lblUsurio = new JLabel("Usuario");
        lblUsurio.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblUsurio.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblUsurio.setBounds(8, 17, 62, 26);
        contentPane.add(lblUsurio);

        JLabel lblSenha = new JLabel("Senha");
        lblSenha.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblSenha.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblSenha.setBounds(20, 54, 50, 26);
        contentPane.add(lblSenha);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(92, 21, 176, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(92, 52, 176, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);

        JLabel lblConectado = new JLabel("");
        lblConectado.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\ambiente_de_trabalho\\teste\\Inbras\\src\\br\\com\\inbras\\icones\\desconectado1.png"));
        lblConectado.setBounds(30, 91, 33, 33);
        contentPane.add(lblConectado);

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.setBounds(92, 101, 176, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnLogin);

    }
}
```

O código está funcionando, só trava na hora da conexão com banco...
Eu desistalei o meu servidor, que é o vertrigo, instalei de novo, não deu certo..
Já instalei o Xampp também, não deu certo travou do mesmo jeito...

O que será que está causando esse erro?

Comment: Como está o uso de RAM, HD e processamento da sua máquina? Pode ser simplesmente que algum processo externo ao Eclipse esteja usando demasiados recursos, ou então que sua RAM esteja cheia e o sistema operacional esteja paginando em disco a memória de trabalho

Comment: meu hd tem 930 gb espaço livre 635gb.

memória em uso(compactada) 3,5gb 
disponivél 4,3 gb

Comment: Galera com muito sofrimento descobrir o que era.
Baixei um aplicativo do banco santander, Plug in G-buster....

Comment: apaguei se plugin e voltou ao normal..